# How to do & operation on binary no.(0b1100) and bin(4)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am finding difficulty performing a bitwise & operation between the `bin()` and `int` in binary form. How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: Why would you try to do that on strings? Just do it on the original integers.

Comment: Do you  mean a bitwise *and* operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to perform the bitwise AND operation (using the `&` operator) on two integers, there is no need to convert them to strings of their binary representations.

Take this example:

```
x = 4 # 0b100
y = 5 # 0b101
print(x & y) # => 4, which is 0b100, because 0b100 & 0b101 = 0b100
```

Comment: Silly Me. I got it, thanks for reminding. I was doing bitwise operation by converting them to binary format, But your's is the better way.

Comment: @ShashankVerma Bitwise operations can only be done on binary numbers. However, all integers are natively stored in binary, so you can directly manipulate them as binary numbers – the number system is interchangeable.